# Android-How to write Wifi access point to xml file?

Tags: android, wifi

How to write Wifi access point to xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
   WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
   wifiInfo.getBSSID();
   wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
   wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
   wifiInfo.getSSID();
   wifiInfo.getNetworkId();

DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
                .newDocumentBuilder();
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = documentBuilder.newDocument();



        org.w3c.dom.Element root = doc
                .createElement("wifiInfo");

        doc.appendChild(root);

        org.w3c.dom.Element bssIdNode = doc
                .createElement("bssId");

        bssIdNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(bssId));
        root.appendChild(bssIdNode);

        org.w3c.dom.Element ipAddNode = doc
                .createElement("ipAdd");
        ipAddNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(ipAdd));
        root.appendChild(bssIdNode);



        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,
                "Yes");

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
         xmlString = sw.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get wifi information using this code-

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
wifiInfo.getBSSID();
wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
wifiInfo.getSSID();
wifiInfo.getNetworkId();
```

For writing to xml file [refer this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)

Answer (score 0):

For the #1's suggestion, it just can get the current connected network information.
The following code snippet may match your requirement:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<ScanResult> mAPList = wm.getScanResult();
for (ScanResult sr : mAPList) {
    //TO-DO
}
```

Don't forget add `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` in your manifest.xml